# DNN5 Skin Produces PageLoad Error

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning

Good Evening,

I uploaded a skin package to my DotNetNuke 5.6.7 site, created a page using my SAEInner Skin and receive the following error message:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: The Controls collection cannot be modified 
because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

The skin makes use of several image tags referencing the images folder in the skin package.  I used the following to reference one such image:

```
img src="<%=SkinPath %>/images/sae-sn-fb.gif"
```

This works fine in the skin used on my site's home page, but an error is created when using the Inner skin.  How would I rectify this?

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use single quotes, like:

```
img src='<%=SkinPath %>/images/sae-sn-fb.gif'
```

Bye,
al.